# Jest and enzyme Passed individuals test but failed to run all

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I have a few tests to remove country, state, and city. When I run them individually they all pass, but if I run them together, the last test failed. It has the mount(and dom) of the previous test! i.e. `expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st State')).toBe(true);` failed, because I have removed it from the previous test, and the snapshot confirm it! Anybody knows why?

In more detail, I have a tree structure like below if I remove the country all states and cities under that country will be removed, and if I remove state all cities under that state and so on.

```
-1st Country(testid=1)
-- 1st State(testid=2)
--- 1st City(testid=3)
--- 2nd City(testid=4)
-- 2nd State(testid=5)
--- 3rd City(testid=6)
```

```js
import ....

jest.mock('../apiWrappers/fetchData');

describe('<App/> Rendering using enzyme', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    fetchData.mockReset();
    fetchData.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(data));
  });

  test('Once loaded and remove the first country', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    await waitForExpect(() => {
      expect(fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      wrapper.update();
    });
    wrapper.find('[data-testid="removeDataRow-1"]').at(0).simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st Country')).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('2nd Country')).toBe(true);
    expect(toJson(wrapper)).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  test('Once loaded and remove the first state', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    await waitForExpect(() => {
      expect(fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      wrapper.update();
    });

    wrapper.find('[data-testid="removeDataRow-2"]').at(0).simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st Country')).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st State')).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st City')).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('2nd City')).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('2nd State')).toBe(true);
  });

  test('Once loaded and remove the first City', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(<App />);
    await waitForExpect(() => {
      expect(fetchData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
      wrapper.update();
    });

    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st State')).toBe(true);
    wrapper.find('[data-testid="removeDataRow-3"]').at(0).simulate('click');

    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st Country')).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st State')).toBe(true);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('1st City')).toBe(false);
    expect(wrapper.text().includes('2nd City')).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

App.js

```js
// @flow
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import FilterSection from '../components/FilterSection';
import Sidebar from '../components/Sidebar';
import fetchData from '../apiWrappers/fetchData';

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [setting, setSetting] = useState({ hide: '3', loadedData: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const newData = await fetchData();
        setData(newData);
        setSetting({ ...setting, loadedData: newData });
        setLoading(false);
      }
      catch (e) {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    getData();
    // eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  const handleRemoveDataRow = (parents:Array<number>) => {
    // remove the country with id === parents[0]
    if (parents.length === 1) {
      let newData = [...data];
      newData = newData.filter(
        item => [parents[0]].indexOf(item.id) === -1,
      );
      setData(newData);
    }
    // remove the state with id === parents[1]
    else if (parents.length === 2) {
      const newData = [...data];
      const countryIndex = newData.findIndex((row) => row.id === parents[0]);
      newData[countryIndex].states = newData[countryIndex].states.filter(
        (item) => [parents[1]].indexOf(item.id) === -1,
      );
      setData(newData);
    } else if (parents.length === 3) {
    // remove the city with id === parents[2]
      const newData = [...data];
      const countryIndex = newData.findIndex((row) => row.id === parents[0]);
      const stateIndex = newData[countryIndex].states.findIndex((row) => row.id === parents[1]);
      newData[countryIndex].states[stateIndex].cities = newData[countryIndex].states[stateIndex]
        .cities.filter(
          (item) => [parents[2]].indexOf(item.id) === -1,
        );
      setData(newData);
    }
  };

  const onChangeFilterValue = (e) => setSetting({ ...setting, hide: e.target.value });
  const onChangeSearch = (e) => {
    if (!loading) {
      const newData = setting.loadedData.filter(
        (x) => x.name.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()),
      );
      setData(newData);
    }
  };
  return (
    <>
      <FilterSection
        onChangeSearch={onChangeSearch}
        onChangeFilterValue={onChangeFilterValue}
        filterValue={setting.hide}
      />
      {!loading
        ? (
          <Sidebar
            items={data}
            onRemoveDataRow={handleRemoveDataRow}
            hide={parseInt(setting.hide, 10)}
          />
        )
        : <span>Loading List</span>}
    </>
  );
};
export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough context about how are you removing those values from your main state, but I think that in your App you are mutating the value of the `data` variable on the second test and it is getting a wrong value on the third one. You can confirm that putting a `console.log(data)` in each test to see the difference (it should be equal for each test). If that is your problem you should not mutate it in your App, a workaround would create a new `data` in your `beforeEach`.

work example mutating `data` with part of your code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/mutating-data?file=index.js

without mutating, creating a new `data`
https://stackblitz.com/edit/creating-a-new-data?file=index.js

Comment: Is there any way I can enforce it in the `beforeEach`. I have already included the following.

`jest.clearAllMocks(); fetchData.mockReset(); fetchData.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve(data));`

I want my test be independent of each other. 

My app is mutable, once they remove it. They could not add it anymore. I have added it to the question.

Thanks!

Comment: I made a change in `beforeEach ` as `fetchData.mockReturnValue(Promise.resolve([...data]));` but still I get the data of previous test each time!

Comment: yep, you can use some library like lodash deepClone.
I think that you are mutating your main object. Keep in mind that `[...data]` are not totally creating a new list, its child is still the same in memory.

Comment: I edited the answer with a working example of mutating and not mutating.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I do mutate it as it does not matter for my app, and I did not know the difference :D :(((

However, even if I make it without mutating, still the test is failed! Let me I create a pull request and add it here. it says `Method “simulate” is meant to be run on 1 node` at `wrapper.find('[data-testid="removeDataRow-3"]').at(0).simulate('click');`

I am quite new with enzyme, please let me know if I have done anything wrong there.

Comment: https://github.com/mandanemedia/ListsOfCounties/blob/fixTests/src/containers/App.2.test.js#L188